# unable to free gpu memory after loading spacy model

Tags: python, spacy, cupy

Why does SpaCy keep GPU memory even after I delete the model? First I thought I'm facing same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63998616/1805756) but then I realized even Cupy doesn't mark the memory as being free.

```
import spacy
import cupy as cp
import time
import gc


def pool_stats(mempool):
    print('used:',mempool.used_bytes(),'bytes')
    print('total:',mempool.total_bytes(),'bytes\n')

pool = cp.cuda.MemoryPool(cp.cuda.memory.malloc_managed) # get unified pool
cp.cuda.set_allocator(pool.malloc) # set unified pool as default allocator

spacy.prefer_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load('/tmp/nlp')
pool_stats(pool)

# used: 2716626944 bytes
# total: 2719709696 bytes

del nlp
time.sleep(3)
gc.collect()
pool_stats(pool)

# used: 2700994560 bytes
# total: 2719709696 bytes
```

Comment: I think this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63998616/cupy-freeing-unified-memory. We have fixed the leak in CuPy v8.0.0, so could you try updating CuPy?

Comment: @kmaehashi SpaCy is not compatible with CuPy v8.0.0 since deprecation of `scatter_add` raises some errors.

Comment: @kmaehashi Also notice that cupy marks the memory to be used still and not free.

Comment: Ah, sorry I was wrong. I tried to reproduce the error with cupy-cuda92 v7.8.0 using `en_core_web_sm` instead of `/tmp/nlp`, but failed (the last status was `used: 0 bytes`). Could you try adding `import gc; print(gc.collect())` after `del nlp` to isolate the issue?

Comment: @kmaehashi It doesn't help.